# Voltage on the Serial Link and Parallel Resistor Value

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, resistors, deserialiser

This question is related to the previous question that I had over [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/562975/voltage-on-the-serial-link?noredirect=1#comment1470032_562975)

I found the serializer that I am using. It is over [here](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX9277-MAX9281.pdf)

From the above serializer datasheet, on page 9, I found that the maximum differential output voltage on the pins OUT+ and OUT- are 0.61V

And the offset voltage maximum value is 1.56V.

So, in this case, the average voltage on the OUT+ and OUT- lines would be 1.56V + (0.61/2) = 1.865V, right?

Is my calculation correct?

And 2nd question, in the deserializer datasheet application diagram over here on [page 74](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX9278-MAX9282.pdf),
what is the purpose of the 49.9K resistor on the IN+ and IN- pins of the deserializer? Isn't it supposed to be 50ohms each for the parallel termination purpose? Why 49.9k instead of 50ohms? Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at figure 2 and mark up the differential voltages: -

[image]

> *So, in this case, the average voltage on the OUT+ and OUT- lines would
> be 1.56V + (0.61/2) = 1.865V, right?*

The average voltage will be between 1.1 volts and 1.56 volts. The peak voltage could be as high as 1.56 volts + 0.61/2 volts = 1.865 volts when driving a 100 Ω termination resistor. It might be nearly twice this into an open circuit.

> *what is the purpose of the 49.9K resistor on the IN+ and IN- pins of
> the deserializer?*

Those components are high value resistors that are used to prevent the link between transmitter and receiver floating to a silly voltage should LMN1 and LMN0 resistors (line fault monitoring) not be fitted. When line fault monitoring is implemented, the 49k9 resistors form part of the voltage divider that permits that functionality: -

[image]

> *Isn't it supposed to be 50ohms each for the parallel termination
> purpose?*

The 100 Ω termination (twisted pair) is inside the deserializer.

Comment: Thank you very much @Andy aka. I checked in the datasheet of the MAX9278 deserializer. I am not able to find the place where they mentioned that the 100ohm termination is placed internal to the deserializer. How did you figure that out?

Comment: It's the top of page 10 of the deserializer data sheet. Use CTRL-F then enter 100 in the box and it's the 14th occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not assume that the average voltage **would be** 1.56 V. The average voltage on a given wire over any period of time would depend on the data, one the **actual** offset voltage, and on the **actual** differential voltage.

49.9 ohms is a standard value, 50.0 is not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The resistor that the deserializer recommends is 49.9k and not 49. That's why I am not able to understand. Why such a high value instead of 49? They are supposed to be parallel termination resistors, right?